# Structure theorem for distributions with support in a variety

Tags: schwartz-distributions

Let $p\in \mathbb{C}[z_1,\cdots, z_d]$, and $V=\{{\mathbf{x}}\in \mathbb{R}^d: p({\mathbf{x}})=0\}$. Let $T\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a distribution whose support is contained in $V$.

Is there a structure theorem describing such $T$?

(In the special case that $V=\{{\mathbf{0}}\}$, we know that that $T$ is a linear combination of the Dirac delta distribution at $\mathbf{0}$ and its partial derivatives, while if $V=S^{d-1}$, then we can write 
$$
T=\sum_{0\leq m\leq M} \partial_r^m T_m, 
$$
where the $T_m$ are distributions on $S^{d-1}$.)